# Connecting a setValue slot of a custom slider so that it is called when changing the value in QSpinBox?

Tags: qt, qt4

I am creating a custom slider class using `QAbstractSlider` as base class. In the main function I have tried `connect(spinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), slider, SLOT(setValue(int)))` but it is not working.

Comment: could you provide some code for your custom slider?

Comment: sorry, code is very big so i can't provide it. Can you tell which part u want. In the above statement  setvalue is predefined function it is not related to user defined.

Comment: You're not giving much detail here. Did you override setValue() and forgot to declare it as a `public slot`? Do you get a debug message telling you about non-existing SIGNALs/SLOTs? Do you actually do something to fire the valueChanged signal? Keep in mind: setValue() will emit valueChanged() **if the new value is different from the old one**.

Comment: Concerning webclectic's request for code and your question "which part of the code": I'd say the class declaration would be a good start, ie. the .h file. :)

Comment: Now the problem is solved i am now not calling the predefined slot. I am now calling the user defined slot.

Answer (score 2):

The connection should work.

Make sure that you have used the Q_OBJECT macro in your class definition. Also in the main.cpp do the following:

Add the following include:

```
#include <QErrorMessage>
```

and add the following line of code

```
QErrorMessage::qtHandler();
```

If there is any problem with Singal /Slot connections a qt dialog will popup.

Comment: I have checked it but in my case not any dialog is popping out even if when i am writing wrong signal slot.